# Tracking cause of 503 errors for certain IP addresses

Tags: varnish, apache2, 503-error

An outside IP address is getting access blocked (though a few rare requests do get through from the IP address) with 503 errors to websites on my Apache2 webserver on a Debian machine. I have determined this by looking at the apache access logs for one of the websites. I have Varnish 3.04 set up on the server as well.

The IP address was able to get to the site just fine up until a couple of days ago. This started just happening out of the blue. I'm assuming this IP address is getting flagged as a bot by varnish (or maybe apache).

How can I track down whether Apache or Varnish is the culprit? And then how do I correct this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The 503 HTTP status typically indicates a problem with the server setup. It's not a block or ban status.

Most likely the problem is due to timeouts being hit by Varnish while communicating to Apache.

You may troubleshoot this via command line using:

```
varnishlog -d -q "BerespStatus == 503"
```

This will show latest in-memory Varnish log entries for “Backend fetch failed” (HTTP 503 error).

You can also check [more commands for troubleshooting the 503 status in Varnish](https://www.getpagespeed.com/troubleshooting/varnish-backend-fetch-failed)

Comment: Thanks for the help. That command yields: `varnishlog: relocation error: varnishlog: symbol VSL_Setup, version LIBVARNISHAPI_1.0 not defined in file libvarnishapi.so.1 with link time reference`

Comment: Try to run ```ldconfig``` and repeat the above command.